# Making a text bold using DOM Events

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm learning JavaScript now, and for practicing, i'm trying to make a text editor. Where you can type something, click a button and make it to upper or lower case, bold and talic. It worked with lower and upper case, but for some reason it doesn't work with bold.

Here's my HTML:

> ```
> <h1 id="text">Escreva seu texto abaixo</h1>
>
> <div id="container">
>     <input type="text" id="type">
> </div>
> <main>
>     <ul>
>         <li class="buttons">
>             <button id="button1">A</button>
>         </li>
>         <li class="buttons">
>             <button id="button2">a</button>
>         </li>
>         <li class="buttons">
>             <button id="button3">B</button>
>         </li>
>         <li class="buttons">
>             <button id="button4">I</button>
>         </li>
>     </ul>
> </main>
> ```

And here's the script:

> ```
> >  let text = document.getElementById("text")
> >         let input = document.getElementById("type")
> >         let button1 = document.getElementById("button1")
> >         let button2 = document.getElementById("button2")
> >         let button3 = document.getElementById("button3")
> >         let button4 = document.getElementById("button4")
> >         let value1 = document.getElementById("type").value
> > 
> > 
> >         button1.onclick = uppercase
> >         button2.onclick = lowercase
> >         button3.onclick = bold
> >         button4.onclick = italic
> > 
> >         function uppercase(){
> >             text.innerHTML = value1.toUpperCase()
> >         }
> > 
> >         function lowercase (){
> >             text.innerText = input.value.toLowerCase()
> >         }
> > 
> >         function bold(){
> >             text.innerText = input.value.style.fontWeight="bold";
> >         }
> ```

The text that will be changed will be the h1, at the top of the HTML. Also, i wrote

> let value = document.getElementById("type").value

to spare me some time, but when i click the button1 (uppercase) the text just disappear. The button2, with input.value worked fine. So why the var value1 makes and the text disappear and why can't i make the text bold?

Thank you!`

Comment: You set the value to what was there when page was loaded.

Comment: Try using input.style.fontWeight instead of input.value.style.fontWeight to bold.

Comment: I tried input.value.style.fontWeight to bold, and it worked, but the text change to "bold", and the input space also get bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are changing the `input.value` to bold. You can't style the `input.value` you should directly change the `input` style.

Also, you can't use the `input.value =` it is not built-in function  like `toUpperCase`, it is style.

Use `input.value.style.fontWeight` may work, but you need to apply it back which click on other element which is messy. The easiest way is to `<b>` so you don't have to worry to change it back.

Also, I problem I have to mentioned, you should declare the input value inside the function, you declare it at the beginning which will always be empty since you assign the value at page loading.

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text")
let input = document.getElementById("type")
let button1 = document.getElementById("button1")
let button2 = document.getElementById("button2")
let button3 = document.getElementById("button3")
let button4 = document.getElementById("button4")


button1.onclick = uppercase
button2.onclick = lowercase
button3.onclick = bold
//button4.onclick = italic

function uppercase() {
let value1 = document.getElementById("type").value
  text.innerHTML = value1.toUpperCase()
}

function lowercase() {
  text.innerText = input.value.toLowerCase()
}

function bold() {
  text.innerHTML = '<b>'+input.value+'</b>'
}
```

```html
<p id="text">Escreva seu texto abaixo</p>

<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="type">
</div>
<main>
  <ul>
    <li class="buttons">
      <button id="button1">A</button>
    </li>
    <li class="buttons">
      <button id="button2">a</button>
    </li>
    <li class="buttons">
      <button id="button3">B</button>
    </li>
    <li class="buttons">
      <button id="button4">I</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

Comment: But he wants the bolded text to be stored in the text! ( text.innerHTML = ?)

Comment: The bold still doesn't work. When i click the button the text changes to "[object CSSStyleDeclaration]".

Comment: @JoséCarlos, sorry my problem , fixed it now. Also, I problem I have to mentioned, you should declare the input value inside the function, otherwise it will always be `undefined`

Comment: Of course, In that case, this is not undefined but is an empty string(""), right?

Comment: Thanks. your answer was excellent. I was not sure, too. so is it the same that I said?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi, yes it is empty string, I just do a typeof check and the type of it is `string`. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but still doesn't seem to work. The text don't get bold, it's just the same text. I'm sorry to bother you!

Comment: @JoséCarlos, no problem at all. That is because the default style  for `h1` is bold so that will make no effect. Try change the `h1` should work

Comment: I also tried this, but it didn't work                                                                                                      let value1 = document.getElementById("type").value
            let value2 = value1.style.fontWeight="bold"
            text.innerText = value2

Comment: @JoséCarlos, I updated the code to `<p>` which works great, you could try. The example you give me will wrong because **you are trying to store the style to a value` which is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

you need to give CSS to the object, not the text
something like this :

```
input.style.fontWeight="bold";
```